# Enabling pretty-printers in eclipse 4.16.0 does not work on Windows 10

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector, gdb

I am using eclipse 4.16.0 and Mingw-w64 on windows 10. The version of my gdb(8.1) supports python. I have python 2.7.9(to be compatible with the version of python I found in the folder of Mingw-w64) on my machine. The problem is when I check the option of "enable pretty printers in variable/ expression tree" in eclipse; this does not work since I cannot still see the elements of std::vector in debugger windows. I searched and I found this page:https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F as a guideline but I think this is not updated since the option of pretty printers already exists in eclipse.
when I ran the `info pretty-printers` in gdb; things seem fine! all the containers and iterators appear. I also check the content of gdbinit and it contains:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0] + '/../../gcc-8.1.0/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

So, I think that this https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport should not be done. Am I right?
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me to figure out what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!
In fact, even with the newest version of eclipse and python-enabled Mingw-w64, there is something that needed to be manually done.
First, make sure that python 2.7 (compatible with the version of what Mingw supports) is properly installed on your system. Meaning that the python path is added to the environments of the system.
Second, the only thing which should be done is modifying .gdbint in following directory in my case :
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\etc
Modify it in a way that indisde '' is the path of python 27

My .gdbint now contains :

python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\share\gcc-8.1.0\python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end

Then, the last step is going to debug configuration; edit configuration/ debugger
You only need to change the gdb command file in the following manner :
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\etc\gdbinit